# why my antivirus is blocking my code to executer...?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I wrote the code on Visual studio code:-

```
//add data at the begining...
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node Node;
struct node{
    int data;
    Node *next;  
};

Node *create_node(int item, Node *next)
{
    Node *new_node = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));

    if(new_node == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error, could not create new node...!");
        exit(1);
    }

    new_node->data = item;
    new_node->next = NULL;

    return new_node;
}

Node *prepend(Node *head, int item)
{
    Node *new_node;
    
    new_node = create_node(item, head);

    return new_node;
}

int main()
{
    Node *n1, *n2, *head, *n3;

    n1 = create_node(10, NULL);

    head = n1;

    head = prepend(head, 20);

    n2 =  head;
    printf("First data = %d", n2->data);
    
    n3 = n2->next;
    printf("Second data = %d", n3->data);

    return 0;
}
```

when I ran it, the result was:-

PS D:\Codes\C programing\Data struc\Linked list> cd "d:\Codes\C programing\Data struc\Linked list" ; if ($?) { gcc linked_list02.c -o linked_list02 } ; if ($?) { .\linked_list02 }

- ...  gcc linked_list02.c -o linked_list02 } ; if ($?) { .\linked_list02 }
- ```
                                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~.
  ```

At line:1 char:115

- ```
                                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed

When I tried to run it again, the result was:-

PS D:\Codes\C programing\Data struc\Linked list> cd "d:\Codes\C programing\Data struc\Linked list" ; if ($?) { gcc linked_list02.c -o linked_list02 } ; if ($?) { .\linked_list02 }
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file linked_list02.exe: Permission denied
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Why is this happening and how can I solve it...?

Comment: In create_node you never use the next param. Looks like a bug, the new_node->next = NULL should be new_node->next = next. Drop a note if this fixes your issue. Currently you not only leak memory but also have null pointer exception.

Comment: it didn't work, man :(
Can you please explain it a little more...?

Answer (score 0):

I confirmed that modifying your `create_node` function corrects the problem.

```
//add data at the begining...
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node Node;
struct node {
  int data;
  Node* next;
};

Node* create_node(int item, Node* next)
{
  Node* new_node = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));

  if (new_node == NULL)
  {
    printf("Error, could not create new node...!");
    exit(1);
  }

  new_node->data = item;
  new_node->next = next; // <- corrected the problem here

  return new_node;
}

Node* prepend(Node* head, int item)
{
  Node* new_node;

  new_node = create_node(item, head);

  return new_node;
}

int main()
{
  Node* n1, * n2, * head, * n3;

  n1 = create_node(10, NULL);

  head = n1;

  head = prepend(head, 20);

  n2 = head;
  printf("First data = %d", n2->data);

  n3 = n2->next;
  printf("Second data = %d", n3->data);

  return 0;
}
```

Compiled in **release** mode with the VSC compiler.

**Explanation** In your original code you never use the `next` argument, thus, when `create_node` is called, the `next` always points to `NULL`.

This makes the `prepend` function to actually ignore the `head` parameter. And this leads directly to the issue here:

```
head = prepend(head, 20);
// oops, head->next is NULL!

n2 = head;
printf("First data = %d", n2->data);

n3 = n2->next;
// n3 is NULL then

printf("Second data = %d", n3->data);
// null pointer, you can't access the data memory on a NULL pointer!
```

Comment: Great, you could possibly accept this answer so that anyone else having similar issue would consider this as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the problem with your code , but by default most preinstalled anitiviruses  block any files with .exe extension thinking as security breach to your system  even if it is a simple 'hello world' program . if there is memory issue with your present code the runtime your spit error when code is executed

you can ether just disable antivirus in control panel when you are coding or about to run your program

or uninstall it as windows defender does a better job than these softwares

Comment: Actually, I didn't have to uninstall the antivirus. I had to tweak some settings in my anti-virus software, and it worked. Thanks a lot, man for your response.